# Vue.js: How to Bind Different Click Events to Components Generated via v-for Loop Using a Function Property

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So i have a list Item component:

```
<template>
  <div
    @click="customEvent"
    class="m-3 mx-auto flex h-fit max-h-fit w-fit cursor-pointer flex-nowrap gap-5 whitespace-nowrap rounded-3xl border-2 border-gray-200 px-14 py-2 font-semibold shadow-xl transition-all duration-300 hover:scale-105 hover:bg-black hover:text-white hover:shadow-2xl"
  >
    <Icon :icon="icon" width="30" height="30" />
    {{ name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Icon } from '@iconify/vue'
import { defineEmits } from 'vue'
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const props = defineProps({
  icon: String,
  name: String
})
const emits = defineEmits('customEvent')
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

The list items are stored in objects, they have diffretn name, icon and call diffren funtion how to make it work using v-for?

```
const sideNavbarListItems = reactive([
  {
    name: 'Resources',
    icon: 'clarity:atom-solid',
    fun: fun1
  },
  {
    name: 'Favorites',
    icon: 'tabler:stars',
    fun: fun2
  }
])
```

and i dont want to have it like

```
<side-navbar-list-item :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name" @click="fun1"></side-navbar-list-item>
<side-navbar-list-item :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name" @click="fun2"></side-navbar-list-item>
<side-navbar-list-item :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name" @click="fun3"></side-navbar-list-item>
```

I want it to work like the, i store object in array, and every object has a diffrent name, icon and function that calls. So in item component i declared props and then used v-for. But how to make it work with @click event and so that every object calls diffrent function is function cant be a prop, and emit also doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

A function can most certainly be a prop. Once you have the function as a prop, using it in a v-for is done the same way you bind the different names and icons.

```js
defineProps({
  icon: String,
  name: String,
  fun: Function
})
```

```html
<side-navbar-list-item
  v-for="item in sideNavbarListItems"
  :key="item.name"
  :icon="item.icon"
  :name="item.name"
  @click="item.fun"
/>
```

If you also need the functions to emit back to the parent then the entire strategy should probably be rethought.  Passing a function from a parent to a child, so the child can invoke a function that emits back to the parent... It's circuitous. The function should exist solely in the parent. At most a child component in this case should only need to emit an event to trigger the function in the parent. If necessary, the parent would only need to pass a specific event name string as a prop for the child to do so.